# How do I Automatically Copy VBA Code Across all Worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that receives a large amount of data from an ERP export.  A macro splits the data into separate tabs (worksheets) based on values in a certain column (SalesPerson).

Within each worksheet, I want a macro that adds functionality to that sheet, i.e. the ability to double click on a row and delete it.  My code works.....

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim resp As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        resp = MsgBox(Prompt:="Delete data from row " & Target.Row & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel)
        If resp = vbYes Then Range(Replace("I#:M#", "#", Target.Row)).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

**....the question I have:**

this macro has to reside in the worksheet level, not the module level.  Is there a way to automatically paste this script into each worksheet that is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Workbook event instead.  It gives you a sheet parameter you can use to identify which sheet the event was triggered from.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

Naturally, this doesn't reside on the `Sheet` object, it can be found on the `ThisWorkbook` object in your VBA editor.

[image: ThisWorkbook]

Comment: Thank you Skin.  Accurate and helpful.

Comment: @Sudenga-Steve, feel free to mark it as the answer then.